# Why narrow casting in java allowed from long to byte

Tags: java, casting, byte, long-integer

We can cast a larger number type, such as a long, into a smaller number type,
such as a byte. for exp:

```
long l = 130L;
byte b = (byte)l;
```

When compile, we don't get a runtime error, even when the value being narrowed is too large
for the type (in this case byte).
Ideally compiler should complain, but it works why?

Comment: Because you told it that's what you wanted to do! If you did `byte b = l` it would throw a compiler error. To remove the error you have to cast. Why would it _still_ warn you after that?!

Answer (score 4):

This works because you explicitly tell the compiler to allow it. You do this by adding `(byte)` before your long variable.

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) (java 7) explains what happens when you do a so-called narrowing cast. It will just discard the most significant bits.

Comment: If you could quote the relevant para of the JLS this would be the perfect answer - SO loves JLS quotes... (although you already have my +1).

Comment: I totally agree, after looking again, I noticed that this actually is the JLS already, but then Oracle's java 7 website for it. I will update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

> Why narrow casting in java allowed from long to byte

Because:

- it can be done *easily*
- it can be done in an *unambiguous*, *straightforward* way
- and it is *useful*.

> When compile, we don't get a runtime error

When you compile, the most you can get is a "*compile time error*". You can get *"runtime error*" when you run the application.

You don't get a compile time error in this case becase you explicitly stated you want it to be converted to `byte`. Casting to `byte` has a type of `byte` which can be assigned to a variable having a type of `byte`.